# For which use was a Pentium D motherboard with 4 x Gigabit Ethernet & 7.1 Audio bought?

Tags: networking, audio, motherboard, ethernet

I just found this very interesting motherboard in the electronics trash:

http://www.commell.com.tw/product/SBC/LV-674.HTM

While 4 x gigabit LAN seems to me fitted to server applications (which this board is certainly not thought for), and leaves me puzzled on its own, I really don't understand why this is paired with a 7.1 audio chip and the dedicated I/O.

Whith which main application in mind would such a board be used for? It seems very specialized and I don't seem to understand the application of these combinations. I wouldn't even see the use of 4 x gigabit LAN, respectively how this would be connected. 4 different networks?

Comment: Could the downvoter explain how this question might be improved?

Comment: I suppose the reason is that only the manufacturer can answer this reliably... Though I guess it _might_ have something to do with network audio streaming, for example.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful comment, I edited the question to ask not for the designated use but for the intentions someone would have if they bought such a motherboard.

Comment: Its useful for whatever you need 4 ethernet ports for. IP camera controller, router...

Comment: But neither an IP camera controller or a router would profit from 7.1 audio... I think this narrows the question down sufficiently enough from the beginning, didn't it? I am asking a big community so that someone with the actual experience can say 'I used this kind of thing for application x', which would make me understand why such motherboards were bought. Why not reopen it for such an answer possibility?

Answer (score 1):

A quick google search brought up a [site](http://www.globalamericaninc.com/commell-lv-674e.html#product_tabs_description_tabbed) that described its usage as "optimized for a broad range of embedded applications such as interactive clients, gaming, medical, POS, Digital Signage, Surveillance and industrial automation equipment."

Comment: +1. Beat me to it. I was going to say such tasks as lecture theatres etc where you may have multiple network-enabled projectors and the 7.1/SPDIF audio out for enhanced audio devices and amplifiers.

Comment: Thanks for the information. But while that sounds more like advertisement blabla, for most things from the list I can either imagine a much better suited solution (gaming, industrial automation) or don't even know what is meant because it's cryptic to me (interactive clients, POS, Digital Signage) or the field is too broad (interactive clients, medical). Surveillance and the lecture theatres seem to make sense, but did surveillance cameras need that bandwidth and use 7.1 sound? Can you go into more detail why this combination would be helpful for any of the tasks?